# Unable to open unix socket in redis - Permission denied while firing up docker container

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, redis, dockerfile

I am trying to fire up a separate redis container which will work as a broker for celery. Can someone help me with as to why the docker user is not able to open the UNIX socket. I have even tried making the user as root but it doesn't seem to work. Please find below the Dockerfile, docker-compose file and redis.conf file.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos/python-36-centos7
USER root
ENV DockerHOME=/home/django
RUN mkdir -p $DockerHOME
ENV PYTHONWRITEBYCODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PATH=/home/django/.local/bin:$PATH
COPY ./oracle-instantclient18.3-basiclite-18.3.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm /home/django
COPY ./oracle-instantclient18.3-basiclite-18.3.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm /home/django
COPY ./oracle.conf /home/django
RUN yum install -y dnf
RUN dnf install -y libaio libaio-devel
RUN rpm -i /home/django/oracle-instantclient18.3-basiclite-18.3.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm && \
            cp /home/django/oracle.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ && \
            ldconfig && \
            ldconfig -p | grep client64
COPY ./requirements /home/django/requirements
WORKDIR /home/django
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r ./requirements/development.txt
COPY . .
RUN chmod 777 /home/django


EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-e", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Docker-compose file:

```
version : '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/django
      - cache:/var/run/redis
    image: app_name:django
    container_name: app_name
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  db:
    image: postgres:10.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
     - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=app_name
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=app_password
      - POSTGRES_DB=app_db
    labels:
      description : "Postgres Database"
    container_name: app_name-db-1
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ./redis/data:/var/lib/redis
      - ./redis/redis-server.log:/var/log/redis/redis-server.log
      - cache:/var/run/redis/
      - ./redis/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
    container_name: redis
    healthcheck:
      test: redis-cli ping
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 30


volumes:
  postgres_data:
  cache:
  static-volume:
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
# run migration first
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py preload_sites -uvasas -l
python manage.py preload_endpoints -uvasas -l
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

#start celery
export C_FORCE_ROOT='true'
celery multi start 1 -A realm -l INFO -c4

# start the server
python manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

redis.conf

```
unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock
unixsocketperm 770

logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log
```

I am new to docker so apologies if I have not done something very obvious or if I have not followed some of the best practices.

Comment: Docker containers usually don't share files, and so you can't typically use a Unix socket to communicate between them.  Can you use the default Redis configuration, and configure your `app` container to connect to `redis:6379` instead?

Comment: I have looked into that option, but that would involve a lot of changes in the existing code. If it is unavoidable, that will be my plan B.